# angular resource overwrite url not working

Tags: angularjs, resources

The documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) says that:

```
url – {string} – action specific url override. 
The url templating is supported just like for the resource-level urls.
```

I would like to use this good feature, I tried this:

```
angular.module("experience", ['ngResource'])

    .factory('Experience', function ($resource, identity) {

    return $resource("api/experiences/:id", {}, {
        queryAll : {
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : 'api/companies/' + identity.id + '/experiences',
            isArray : true
        }
    });
});
```

You see I am trying to overwrite the url for queryAll method. but this does not work, the query still sends the url api/experiences. is this really supported or I am doing somehting wrong? thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? I am using this feature successfully with Angular 1.1.4. The difference in my case is the parametric original URL, i.e. I have something like `$resource("api/xxx",...)` instead of yours `$resource("api/xxx/:id",..)`

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am using the newest version 1.2. I guess  api/xxx or api/xxx/:id does not affact anything?

Comment: I guess it *should* not affect anything, but you never know :) By the way there is another difference: I am using POST, not GET.

Comment: thanks...I tried both,,,neither works. very strange...

Comment: This is not working for me either in 1.2.4.  Did you figure this out?

Comment: no, sorry. welcome to post an answer if anyone sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very similar problem in my project. The url couldn't be overridden in resource actions. I am using Angular 1.2.0 and it should support the feature since 1.1.4. So I checked the Angular API reference, CHANGELOG, but no luck. Then I dug into the source code and noticed that the logic of overriding url isn't there. That's the root cause of the problem. I updated Angular to 1.2.0, but I forgot to update `angular-resource.js` to the corresponding version.

So, long story short: **check the version of angular-resource.js**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you cann access properties of `identity` in the url override, but you can try something like this:

```
return $resource("api/experiences/:id", {}, {
    queryAll : {
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : 'api/companies/:id/experiences',
        params  : { id: identity.id },
        isArray : true
    }
});
```

The `id: identity.id` tells angular to use the id property of `identity`, (if it exists).